# Mapping-Class Groups of Subsurfaces of a Hyperbolic Surface

Tags: riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, moduli-space, teichmueller-theory, mapping-class-group

Assume that $\mathcal{R}$ is a hyperbolic surface with $m$ geodesic boundary components and $n$ punctures. If $\mathcal{R}'$ is a *closed* subsurface of a hyperbolic surface $\mathcal{R}$, then there is an inclusion homomorphism between the mapping class groups:

$$\text{Mod}(\mathcal{R}')\longrightarrow \text{Mod}(\mathcal{R})$$

I am concerned with the situation where $\mathcal{R}''$ is a general subsurface of $\mathcal{R}$. Such a surface has some handles, a number of boundaries, and a number of punctures. The presence of punctures makes the surface non-closed assuming that the boundary curves belong to the boundaries of $\mathcal{R}''$. It is possible some of the boundaries and/or punctures of $\mathcal{R}''$ are also boundaries and/or punctures of $\mathcal{R}$, i.e :

$$\partial\mathcal{R}''\cap \partial\mathcal{R}\ne \emptyset$$

Here a mapping-class **fixes the boundary but can permute the punctures**.

There are two questions:

- Is there an inclusion homomorphism between the mapping-class groups in this case, i.e. does a homomorphism $\text{Mod}(\mathcal{R}'')\longrightarrow \text{Mod}(\mathcal{R})$ exist?
- If yes, when does such a homomorphism is injective? In particular, when $\text{Mod}(\mathcal{R}'')$ is a subgroup of $\text{Mod}(\mathcal{R})$?

The case where the mapping-class group fixes the puncture and all of the boundaries of $\mathcal{R}''$ belong to the interior of $\mathcal{R}$ is treated in [Geometric Subgroups of Mapping Class Groups](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9906122.pdf).

Comment: The question is not very well formulated, it looks like there are some unintended consequences to the current formulation. For example,  you are not requiring that $\mathcal{R}''$ have finitely many punctures, nor that the boundary have finitely many components, nor that those components be compact. So $\mathcal{R}''$ could be the complement of a Cantor set embedded in the interior of $\mathcal{R}$, or the complement of a Cantor set embedded in the boundary of $\mathcal{R}$.

Comment: For a simple example, if $\mathcal{R}'' = \mathcal{R}-\{p\}$ for some point $p$ in the interior of $\mathcal{R}$ then a homomorphism is defined $\text{Mod}(\mathcal{R}'') \mapsto \text{Mod}(\mathcal{R})$. But that homomorphism is not injective, in fact its kernel is isomorphic to the fundamental group of $\mathcal{R}$, according to the Birman exact sequence.https://math.berkeley.edu/~qchu/Notes/274/Lecture3.pdf

Comment: Dear Prof @LeeMosher, thank you very much for the answer. However, I had another question. Let's say that the surface $\mathcal{R}''$ can be obtained from the surface $\mathcal{R}$ by removing a pair of pants. There are four possibilities: 1) Remove two geodesic boundary components using a third curve inside $\mathcal{R}$ (these three curves make a pair of pants) 2) Remove two punctures using a third curve inside $\mathcal{R}$; 3) Remove a single boundary  using two curves inside $\mathcal{R}$;

Comment: 4) Remove a single puncture using two curves inside $\mathcal{R}$. In this situation, is the inclusion homomorphism injective?

Comment: I'll make my comment into an answer. Then, as you generate new questions, what works best on this site is not to bury them in comments to your old question, but instead to post a new question. Otherwise, the new questions and their answers stay buried in old comments where no-one will ever see them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first question has a simple negative answer. Suppose that $\mathcal{R}$ is a closed oriented surface and $\mathcal{R}'' = \mathcal{R}-p$ for some point $p$ in the interior of $\mathcal{R}$. Then a canonical homomorphism 
$$\text{Mod}(\mathcal{R}'') \mapsto \text{Mod}(\mathcal{R})
$$
is defined, because every homeomorphism of $\mathcal{R}''$ has a unique extension to a homeomorphism of $\mathcal{R}$. But the kernel of this homomorphism is isomorphic to the fundamental group of $\mathcal{R}$, according to the [Birman short exact sequence](http://math.berkeley.edu/~qchu/Notes/274/Lecture3.pdf), hence the homomorphism is not injective.